# Is there a daemon which is not a server?

Tags: daemon, init

It seems that  a server is not necessarily running as a daemon, e.g. [X server](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/232160/definitions-arguments-of-daemon-and-server). [If I am not correct, please let me know.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/489971/why-is-the-x-server-process-not-a-daemon)

Is a daemon necessarily a server? Is there a daemon which is not a server? I guess there are quite a few, and [I am not sure if the `init` processes under sysvinit and  systemd are such examples](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/489916/do-server-and-clients-depend-on-different-ipc-ways).

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I am using Linux only, so it is hard for me to relate

Comment: That may be easier to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything that is performing a task without being requested to do so by a client.  I.e. a daemon that is not serving clients.

I've recently played around with SSHGuard, a daemon that parses connection logs and that blocks abusive hosts.  This is not a server.

The DHCP client daemon that many Unices runs variations of is not a server.

NTP is often implemented as a daemon that can function without being a server (only as a leaf node client).

Comment: `fail2ban` (similar to SSHGuard) and `smartd` (monitoring of S.M.A.R.T values) are two other examples that come to mind.

Comment: `acpid`, `mcelog`, `irqbalance`, `rngd`, `atd`, and `cron`are all additional examples that come to mind.

Answer (score 0):

I am moving Mark's comment here

> https://www.tuhs.org//cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/src/cmd/update.c is a daemon that is not a server.